# Sort string array by alphabet and display values

Tags: c++, sorting, output

I am trying to sort an array with is filled with string values by alphabet. It already works with integers. I think the problem isn’t about the sorting, it is about displaying it.

But here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Ticket {
    int ticketnr;
    string name;
public:
    Ticket() {
        ticketnr = 0;
        name = "NN";
    };
    Ticket(int _tickernr, string _name) {
        ticketnr = _tickernr;
        name = _name;
    }
    friend bool upSort(Ticket a, Ticket b);
};

bool upSort(Ticket a, Ticket b) {
    return (a.name > b.name);
}
int main() {

    Ticket vip(1435, "Beckenbauer");
    Ticket frei;

    Ticket array[10] = {vip, Ticket(2100, "Maier")};
    sort(array, array + 10, upSort);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout << array[i] << endl;

}
```

Xcode says: invalid operands to binary expression

Thank you and best regards
Flo

Comment: You have to provide an overloaded operator `<<` for your class.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably nothing wrong with the `sort`. What is clearly wrong is that you don't have an `ostream& operator<<` for `Ticket`, so you cannot do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout << array[i] << endl;
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So,

```
friend
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Ticket& t)
{
  return o << t.ticketnr << " " << t.name;
}
```